# Not able to use third party jar in hadoop java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to join two datasets.. One of which is json.. 
I am relying on json-simple library to parse that json..
I am trying to use libjars.. So far .. for simple data processing.. the approach has worked.. but now i am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/ParseException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:820)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.MultipleInputs.getMapperTypeMap(MultipleInputs.java:141)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.DelegatingInputFormat.getSplits(DelegatingInputFormat.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:1024)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1041)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$700(JobClient.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:959)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:912)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:912)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:500)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:530)
    at org.select.Driver.run(Driver.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.select.Driver.main(Driver.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.parser.ParseException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
```

I think I have implemented toolrunner.

```
hadoop jar domain_gold.jar org.select.Driver \
-libjars json-simple-1.1.1.jar  $INPUT1 $INPUT2 $OUTPUT
```

The code
http://pastebin.com/7XnyVnkv

Answer (score 0):

Place your third party JAR file on one of hadoop's default lib folder. For example,  $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib.